# Ionic 4 native camera and gallery access

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a simple ionic 4 app..  All native api working well but when I use the native camera to access the gallery i am getting the user interface of recent photos 
That is not the native user interface in my device. Gallery. 
I can access my native interface from the sidebar and there is a  option of gallery. 
 How can i load that directly without getting this in first place.